# Одна кнопка сортировки вместо двух.

Tags: javascript

```
<a class="app_store_new_b" href='#' onclick="getAppList(9,'con','title','asc')">Название &#9650;</a>
<a class="app_store_new_b" href='#' onclick="getAppList(9,'con','title','desc')">Название &#9660;</a>
```

как можно сделать, чтобы это была одна кнопка? При клике по ней сортировка вверх-вниз  - сейчас это 2 разные кнопки.

Я начал делать, но как-то громозко получается на js+css... Думаю, что есть простое решение, но знаний не хватает

Comment: на чистом js или можно на jquery?

Comment: на jquery даже предпочтительнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

элементарно же:

```
var data = [1,-6,11,3,9,7]
,   sortData = (function(){ 
        var flag = true  // создаём флаг
        ,   predicates = {
                'asc' : function(a, b){ return (a>b) - (b>a) }
            ,   'desc': function(a, b){ return (a<b) - (b<a) }
            }
        return function(data){
            flag = !flag // который при каждом вызове переключаем
            data.sort(predicates[flag ? 'asc' : 'desc']) 
                         // и сортируем в зависимости от его значения
        }
    }())
sortData(data)
console.log(data) // [11, 9, 7, 3, 1, -6]
sortData(data)
console.log(data) // [-6, 1, 3, 7, 9, 11]
sortData(data)
console.log(data) // [11, 9, 7, 3, 1, -6]
sortData(data)
console.log(data) // [-6, 1, 3, 7, 9, 11]
```

интерактивный пример: http://jsfiddle.net/psmm6/2/

Comment: Спасибо большое. А то я навыдумывал с display:none  порнографию.